# Запуск React модуля внутри Spring Boot приложения

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, spring, maven

Я делаю приложение `Spring Boot` + `React`. Вопрос в том, как запустить модуль React внутри Spring Boot приложения. Maven плагины я уже настроил и сам модуль собирается в `.jar`, всё работает отлично.

Просто `React` приложение запускается с помощью `Node.js` на отдельном порту и у меня возникли трудности: как внутри `Spring Boot` приложения стартануть сервер `Node.js`? Может быть я вообще не в ту сторону смотрю, так что не ругайте.

Comment: Что имеете в виду под React приложением? Если это SPA, то вы просто собираете приложение и размещаете его в ресурсах Spring Boot.
Вот пример такого https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-spa

Comment: Нет, это не SPA. Просто отдельный модуль React, который после запуска Maven собирается и упаковывается в .jar вместе с проектом, а мне нужно получить доступ к index.html